# Lowercase and replace unwanted substrings from dataframe header in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, strip

I want to `lowercase` and remove first `s` from the header of a dataframe: `'id', 'sTitle', 'sSource', 'sDate', 'sAbstract', 'sStart_Time', 'sSite', 'sUrl'`.

The expected header will like this: `'id', 'title', 'source', 'date', 'abstract', 'start_time', 'site', 'url'`

I have tried with: `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().lstrip('s')`, it generate an error: `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'lstrip'`.

How can I do that correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `.str` again:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('s').str.lower()
```

---

**Edit:**

After discussing with the OP, this was the final working code:

```
cols = ['sAbstract', 'sStart_Time']
df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns.tolist()).replace({k: k.lstrip('s').lower() for k in cols})
```

Comment: Thank you. If I only want to deal with only `'sAbstract', 'sStart_Time'` two columns?

Comment: `cols = ['sAbstract', 'sStart_Time'], df.cols = df.cols.str.lower().str.lstrip('s')` doesn't work.

Comment: `df[cols].columns.str.lower()...` is what you're looking for @ahbon

Comment: Just tried `cols = ['sAbstract', 'sStart_Time'], df[cols].columns = df[cols].columns.str.lower().str.lstrip('s')`, the columns's names didn't change. Any ideas?

Comment: @ahbon try using: `cols = ['sAbstract', 'sStart_Time'];df.columns = df.columns.replace({k: k.lower().lstrip('s') for k in cols})`

Comment: Ok, let me try. Thanks. Another problem, `lstrip('s')` seems replace two `s` from left of `sStart_Time`, it becomes `tart_time`, do you have ideas to deal with this?

Comment: @ahbon Try doing strip in the front, i edited my answer

Comment: I modified your code to `cols = ['sAbstract', 'sStart_Time'];df.columns = df.columns.str.replace({k: k.lower().lstrip('s') for k in cols})`, it generates: `TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'`

Comment: @ahbon Try using: `cols = ['sAbstract', 'sStart_Time'];df.columns = df.columns.replace({k: k.lstrip('s').lower() for k in cols})`

Comment: I have tried, it generates: `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'replace'`. So I add `.str`

Comment: @ahbon Try using: `cols = ['sAbstract', 'sStart_Time'];df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns.tolist()).replace({k: k.lstrip('s').lower() for k in cols})`

Comment: Great, this works, you may replace this with your code in answer. Thank u.